# why Segmentation fault occurs in the following C code

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a1 {
    int value ;
};

struct cf {
   struct a1 *a1;
   int val;
};

main(){

   struct cf *cf = malloc(sizeof(struct cf));

   cf->a1->value = 45;
   printf("cf->a1->value = %d \n",cf->a1->value);

}
```

when I am tying to execute this C code I'm getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) !

Comment: You've allocated space for `cf`, but do you have any reason to suppose that its `struct a1` pointer, `a1`, points to accessible memory? `cf->a1` is a meaningless value, and you shouldn't be trying to dereference it.  You need an intervening `cf->a1 = malloc(sizeof(struct a1));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you're allocating the required memory for `cf` but not for `a1`.
You have to do something like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a1 {
    int value ;
};

struct cf {
   struct a1 *a1;
   int val;
};

main(){

   struct cf *cf = malloc(sizeof(struct cf));
   cf->a1 = malloc(sizeof(struct a1));
   cf->a1->value = 45;
   printf("cf->a1->value = %d \n",cf->a1->value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the segmentation fault because you haven't allocated memory for `a1`.
You should also cast the malloc from `void*` to `struct cf*` and declare the main function as `int main()` and `return 0` if everything goes well.
Here is a solution to your problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a1 {
    int value ;
};

struct cf {
   struct a1 *a1;
   int val;
};

int main(){

   struct cf *cf = (struct cf*)malloc(sizeof(struct cf));
   cf->a1=(struct a1*)malloc(sizeof(struct a1));

   cf->a1->value = 45;
   printf("cf->a1->value = %d \n",cf->a1->value);

}
```

Comment: you don't cast `malloc` in C - [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @crashmstr if you use gcc you will get a syntax error if you don't cast

Comment: You should not get a syntax error with a C compiler, C++ on the other hand, yes, you would need to. Question is tagged C though.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc(sizeof(struct cf));` here you are allocating memory for struct `cf` which has members as a pointer `a1` & `val`. Pointer `a1` points to struct type `a1` which has member `value` in it. But the `malloc()` allocates only memory for pointer but it doesn't allocate memory for member which it has i.e `value`. There you are trying to write `45` to a unknown memory.

Allocate memory for struct `a1` too as, `cf->a1 = malloc(sizeof(struct a1));`